# Read UDID from iPhone programmatically through a iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code

I would like to generate a QR code that is based on the iPhone UDID number. Is this possible?

Comment: two separate things, if you can get the value, you can generate the QR code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can fetch your UUID by :

```
let uuid =   UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

and then use it to create QR code

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "Any Parameter Name") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: uuid)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```